# Should I save callbacks list in a file?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm training a nmt model with keras. I have kinda memory limitation so I train my model with chunks of data everytime. This is the part of my code related to callbacks:

```
if not os.path.isfile('./model.h5'):
    # define model
    print("Defining the model for the first time: ")
    model = define_model(answer_vocab_size, question_vocab_size, answer_length, question_length, 256)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only=False)
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=15, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
else:
    print("Updating the previous model ....")
    model = load_model(filename)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only=False)
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=15, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

So I have like 10 files and each file have 100000 data. My memory can only afford 10000. So when I run this, one file get picked and my model get trained with whole data in 10 stages. Actually that part of code that I pasted runs in the loop for 10 times.
So I have a little problem, When I run this code for a file, It always start the loss with a number like 7 and in the last stage, decreases to a number like 4. When a pick a new file, the loss at the beginning should be a better one, right? But the same numbers! 
I think since in every run, my variable `callbacks_list` destroys, this can cause problems. Should I save callbacks list in a file? 
Any advice would be appreciated.